# Mean Stack: Can we use both body-parser and multer middleware together?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer, body-parser

I am making a MEAN shop app. I am having trouble in storing images to db. I am using both `body-parser` and `multer`. Can we use both the middlewares together?

Here is the `server.js` file:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path');
var http = require('http');
var multer = require('multer');

var app = express();
var api = require('./server/routes/api');

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));

var upload = multer({
  dest: path.join(__dirname, '/server/public/images'),
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/meanshopcart')));
app.use('/api', api.router);
app.post('/userlogin', api.login);
app.post('/sign-up', api.signup);
app.post('/product', upload.single('productimage'), api.addProduct);
app.use(api.authenticate);

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/meanshopcart/index.html'));
});
```

The `addProduct` function:

```
function addProduct(req, res, next) {
  console.log("adding new product");

  var newProduct = new Product({
    productName: req.body.productname,
    productCategory: req.body.productcategory,
    productDescription: req.body.productdescription,
    productPrice: req.body.productprice
  });

  newProduct.productImage.data = fs.readFileSync(req.file);
  newProduct.productImage.contentType = 'image/jpg';

  newProduct.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error saving product");
      res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Error processing request ' + err
      });
    } else {
      console.log("product inserted");
      res.status(201).json({
        success: true,
        message: 'Product added successfully.'
      });
    }
  });
}

module.exports = {
  router,
  signup,
  login,
  authenticate,
  addProduct
};
```

Comment: you can simply store it as a string. convert the image in base64 and then store it as a string. And the other way you can do is store the image at some location and store that image location in your db. This way your database won't be heavy

Comment: trying to store the image location but there is an issue in receiving the file `req.file`, It is `undefined`. I am uploading the addProduct function above.